# Xpath: Select siblings with matching attribute values

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to write an Xpath query that selects siblings with matching attribute values. So, given this xml file, I want to get the first `eTree` (two siblings with the same `index` value) but not the second (two siblings with different `index` values):

```
<eTree Label="IP-SUB">
  <eTree Label="NP-SBJ" index="1" id="node-567">
  <eLeaf Notext="*exp*" id="node-568"/>
  </eTree>
  <eTree Label="NP-SE" index="1" id="node-572">
  <eTree Label="CL" id="node-573">
  <eLeaf Text="se" tokid="w-192" id="node-574"/>
  </eTree>
</eTree>

<eTree Label="IP-SUB">
  <eTree Label="NP-SBJ" index="1" id="node-567">
  <eLeaf Notext="*exp*" id="node-568"/>
  </eTree>
  <eTree Label="NP-SE" index="2" id="node-572">
  <eTree Label="CL" id="node-573">
  <eLeaf Text="se" tokid="w-192" id="node-574"/>
  </eTree>
</eTree>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

One possible XPath that will return `eTree` elements if it has : child `eTree` with `index` attribute matches `index` of the nearest following sibling `eTree`

```
//eTree[eTree[@index=following-sibling::eTree[1]/@index]]
```

**<kbd>[`Xpathtester Demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/52ca8c5012740176390d9663fe66072d)</kbd>**

**input xml for demo :**

```
<root>
<eTree Label="IP-SUB">
  <eTree Label="NP-SBJ" index="1" id="node-567">
  <eLeaf Notext="*exp*" id="node-568"/>
  </eTree>
  <eTree Label="NP-SE" index="1" id="node-572">
  <eTree Label="CL" id="node-573"/>
  <eLeaf Text="se" tokid="w-192" id="node-574"/>
  </eTree>
</eTree>

<eTree Label="IP-SUB">
  <eTree Label="NP-SBJ" index="1" id="node-567">
  <eLeaf Notext="*exp*" id="node-568"/>
  </eTree>
  <eTree Label="NP-SE" index="2" id="node-572">
  <eTree Label="CL" id="node-573"/>
  <eLeaf Text="se" tokid="w-192" id="node-574"/>
  </eTree>
</eTree>
</root>
```

**output :**

```
<eTree Label="IP-SUB">
  <eTree Label="NP-SBJ" id="node-567" index="1">
  <eLeaf Notext="*exp*" id="node-568"/>
  </eTree>
  <eTree Label="NP-SE" id="node-572" index="1">
  <eTree Label="CL" id="node-573"/>
  <eLeaf Text="se" id="node-574" tokid="w-192"/>
  </eTree>
</eTree>
```